# Servidor bloquea SQLConexion a SQL Server c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, server

Tengo un Web Service que al montarlo en un servidor facilmente me hace conexion a una bd que esta en otro server, el problema que tengo es que al montarlo en el server donde va a quedar instalado permanentemente al querer hacer conexion a la bd me la rechaza aunque sea el mismo programa identico (y no, no esta configurado como localhost ni 127.0.0.1), que podria ser? podria ser un puerto cerrado?

uso: System.Data.SqlClient;

El error que recibo es:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.)

Comment: Pega tu codigo, como haces la conexion en el web service?

Comment: Revisa el firewall también y que la IP de la conexión sea la correcta

Comment: Hola perdon, no habia cachado el error hasta ahora: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.) - 3/31/2020 11:40:44 AM
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.)

Comment: Jose Bardales: La ip es correcta, en otro servidor no me marca ese error.

Comment: Deberias pasarla la consulta al administrador del servidor para que chequee que este todo en condiciones, no te bloquee nada.

Answer (score 0):

Ese error da en SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 y 2014, cuando no tienen instalado el ultimo Service Pack. Con instalarlo en el servidor, ya tendrás soporte para TLS 1.2

2008:
https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=44271

2012:
https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=56040

2014:
https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=51186